# Is there a way to handle the onClick for the delete button in Antd Upload?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, antd

[image: Antd upload delete button]

The file upload works fine. The way I have implemented the upload is that it pushed the file to a 'temp' folder. What I want is when someone clicks the delete (trash icon), I want to capture that and delete the remote file as well.

Is there any handler/onChange function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Antd Upload control has an `onRemove()` callback which sends the file. This is from [their documentation](https://ant.design/components/upload/#API):

> **onRemove**: A callback function, will be executed when removing file button is clicked, remove event will be prevented when return value is
>   false or a Promise which resolve(false) or reject

So, you can wire up the call to remove the remote file in the `onRemove()` callback, and if that call fails (promise is rejected), the file will not be removed from the upload control.